# MySQL - Print string on mysql error

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

Explanation:

I want to insert string in the result of the query

For example: when I'm navigating to (this site is only for for learning):

```
http://www.toplinks.co.il/website.php?id=-1+group+by+1
```

the page is **not** contains "Warning: mysql_fetch_array():"

When I'm navigating to :

```
http://www.toplinks.co.il/website.php?id=-1+group+by+99
```

the site **contains** "Warning: mysql_fetch_array():"

I want to do something like:

when there is a mysql error :

```
print "[Error!]"
```

and when there is no error:

```
print Null
```

Is there a MySQL function that can print string when mysqlerror?

Something like:

```
group_concat(group+by+1,0x5b4572726f72215d)
```

Comment: What about hiding errors in page, checking if error exists and then printing your message?

Answer (score 0):

The function to fetch an error is called:

```
mysql_error()
```

This returns the last error.

The easiest way to use this (in learning code), is the following:

```
mysql_query("YOUR QUERY HERE") or die(mysql_error());
```

I would never recommend doing this in a production website though. It is mainly a quick and ugly way to debug. The "or die()" code snippet can be used after any function that returns a boolean, so as long as your function returns true on success and false on faliure, you can use this after any mysql function

Comment: "http://www.toplinks.co.il/" is not my site., im trying to insert string into the page (like xss) by mysql...

Comment: Ah ok, that makes things much more complicated, I do not believe it is possible to do what you require, I may be proved wrong.